# Can I write my simple Python code in a better way?

Tags: python

I should rewrite my own function in a better way. The function takes an iterator and a sequence of boolean functions and returns an iterator of the elements in the input iterator which returns a truthy value.

```
def allTrue (iterator, funz):
for i in iterator:
    count = 0
    for f in funz:
        if f(i):
            count = count+1
        if count==len(funz):
            yield i
```

I tried to write this:

```
def allTrue2 (iterator, funz):
    return (filter (f , iterator) for f in funz)
```

But it's wrong. How could I improve the code?

Output:

```
print(list(allTrue(range(50),
               (lambda x: x % 3 == 0,
                lambda x: x > 10,
                lambda x: x < 44)
               )))

>>> [12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36, 39, 42]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def allTrue(iterator, funz):
    for i in iterator:
        if all(f(i) for f in funz):
            yield i
```

Answer (score 7):

And if you want a one-liner, just for completeness:

```
def allTrue (iterator, funz):
    return (i for i in iterator if all(f(i) for f in funz))
```

Note that this returns a generator, so it has the same effect as using `yield`.

Answer (score 3):

You can yield from a generator expression like this:

```
def allTrue(iterator, funz):
    yield from (i for i in iterator if all(f(i) for f in funz))
```

Answer (score 0):

Keeping things close to your initial approach, you might use a `for/else` to break once a function returns `False` and move on to the next element. Only if all functions returned `True` and the loop never broke, the `else` part will be executed and `yield` this result:

```py
def allTrue (iterator, funz):
    for i in iterator:
        for f in funz:
            if not f(i):
                break
        else:
            yield i
```

---

Regarding your `filter` approach, you basically created an iterator of iterators. You have an iterator filtering the list according to each function **separatly**. You want to filter the list, returning **a single** iterator, with the condition that **all** functions return `True`:

```py
def allTrue2 (iterator, funz):
    return filter(lambda i: all(f(i) for f in funz), iterator)
```